# Adding region in parallax website

Tags: 7

Hi I am using Surreal theme for my drupal website, it has regions like "Home, about, projects, and contact us" I want to add one more region like "projects" but i am not getting the way to do the settings.
Tried with adding the region using code in .info file but that couldn't work.

Comment: You can try to search for any given region and duplicate all the code referring to it while renaming eg. ``home`` to ``projects``. .info, .tpl and template.php should show up in your search results.